# Macbook pro not turning on

Tags: macbook-pro, charging

I have 2016 MacBook Pro non-touch bar model. One day while using it I connected charger with it and as I connected charger it shut down.

I tried to turn it on and tried SMC reset but it did not turn on.

It has been 3-4 months and I have still not able to turn it on. When I put macbook on charging I feel vibration on its body that we normally feel while charging so I think it is atleast charging and not complete dead. But it is not turning on.

Can someone please help me understand what can be issue.

Comment: were you able to turn t on?

Comment: @techmagister, yes, check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have kept it in bag with 2 small silica gel for 4-5 months and I kept on checking every 15 days whether it is turning on and suddenly after 5 months one day when I connected to charger I got sound (chime when macbook is connected with charger). And when I pressed power button it turned on.

I was happy to see my macbook working again after long time. And I am very happy I did not   visit apple store or third party store(due to lockdown) to get it repaired as it could have cost lot of money. (Because of my experience with apple store they always say your motherboard is damaged).

I am not sure what was issue and why it started working again after few months.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sensor to detect moisture that will shut down  a Mac.  There are [moisture indicator strips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_contact_indicator) that will let a technician know if it was exposed to liquid, howver.

Now, if you got the MacBook wet, it can cause damage to the logic board where it will stop working.  Note that I didn’t use the term “shut down.”  This is because liquid damage can short out electrical contacts causing the machine to simply power off where you lose data unlike a shut down that *cleanly* turns off your computer.  It’s like pulling the plug on a desktop machine.

It may be too late, but you should still review this post:  [What procedure should be followed post spilling fluids onto a MacBook keyboard?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/392674/119271)

The fact that it doesn’t turn on at all means you need to take it in for service.

Comment: I did not get it wet. I just think it is possible that in rainy season may be mositure in air reach inside.

Comment: Not unless you live in a sauna.  Either way, you can't turn it on so it has to go in for service.