# How to fix damage caused by a water spill?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, speakers, damage

There was water spilled on my MacBook Air but I replaced the internal speakers.

Now the sound is not working at all. No internal speaker or microphone is showing up and also the sound does not work with headphones plugged in. Tried reinstalling software, resetting NVRAM, and SMC. When running system_profiler SPAudioDataType I get

```
Jakes-MacBook-Air:~ jakemacbook$ system_profiler SPAudioDataType

Audio:
    Devices:
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to fix this or what I have to replace?

Comment: Internal components oxidate slowly after water spills.

Comment: is there a component i can change inside to fix the speakers/headphone jack?

Comment: Did you work initially after you changed the speakers?

Comment: See this for a cautionary tale:  [What procedure should be followed post spilling fluids onto a MacBook keyboard?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/392675/119271).  That said, why would you believe that reinstalling software would address physical damage?  This is like crashing your car and hoping an oil change and topping off the tank will fix it.  You need to take it in for service.

Comment: @Allan - yours looks a better canonical dupe. You should be able to edit it into the dupes list above because you have the gold badge. I've done it once but don't recall the exact method. Maybe check with the mods in chat if it's not obvious.