# Macbook Pro Water Damage - Now only boots while holding shift key. Crashes as soon as released

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, crash

I have a 2015 Macbook Pro that had a small amount of water spilled on it. Everything seemed fine for a few days. Then it stopped booting properly and crashed after the chime but before the Apple logo. The only way I can make it boot beyond that is holding down the shift key, so in Safe Mode. However, once at the login screen as soon as I release the shift key to enter the password it crashes. I can hold the shift key for minutes without crashing but a few seconds after releasing it crashes every time.

I have taken out all the components and can't see any moisture, corrosion, or signs of damage to the logic board. I have let it dry for 4 days with a fan and heater.

What could be wrong do you think? Would the shift key issue suggest a keyboard replacement might work?

Help greatly appreciated!

Comment: "Everything seemed fine for a few days" …that's the few days that corrosion sets in. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/392675/119271

Comment: Yes I understand that. Like I said I can't see any sign of corrosion but there is obviously damage. Any helpful suggestions?

Comment: Is there a way I can unplug the keyboard from the logic board to test if that is the problem? Or some other way?

Comment: The link provided has lots of good advice including, "Removing all power and getting it to a competent technician within hours of the spill - not days is the only sure fire way to protect and contain liquid damage..." Just because you can't **see** corrosion does not mean it's not there.

Comment: If you want to edit this to clarify left shift or to right shift and internal or external keyboard, that might narrow which part to repair, but close inspection and testing will tell you precisely what component failed on your Mac. (Or run a minimal system on the bench to isolate the top case from the board and screen.)

Comment: Hi bmike, Good point I'd not fully tested that. After more testing it is only the integrated keyboard that enables it to not crash. It is also not just the shift keys that keep it from crashing, it appears to be Escape or Tab (what I've tested so far). I can also now log on as long as I'm holding down tab. As soon as I release keys it crashes

Comment: OK the plot thickens. If I'm logged in and I release all keys it brings up the prompt "Are you sure you want to shut down your computer now" shortly before switching off.

Comment: In case anyone finds this useful I tested booting without the keyboard and battery attached and it booted fine, so it appears the keyboard needs replacing. I tried Isopropanol on the power key with no joy. I am waiting for the keyboard delivery now.