# Extended keyboard numeric keys no longer working after cleaning

Tags: keyboard

I have an extended keyboard for iMac, and after cleaning my keyboard the lines with keys 7, 8, 9 and "-" on the right side don't work any more. There is no such problem with the rest of the numbers. What do you suggest?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/392675/119271 - but you've less chance with just a keyboard, as they're not designed to be taken apart at all. It's time for a new keyboard, really. [You can get the wired aluminium ones on eBay for about $£€ 40. The wireless ones are 140.] Next time… less liquid. Wet a microfibre & wring it out as dry as you can get it. No spray, no cleaning products.

Comment: I called service and they told me to buy a new one.

Comment: @Tetsujin
 thanx

Comment: Yup. they're not really fixable, as you need a heat gun to break the glue; if you heat it too much you wreck the circuitry, not enough & you bend the aluminium… A repair shop won't be bothered with all the effort when you can buy a new one for less than it would cost for them to even attempt a repair.

Comment: I always keep one in reserve - accidents do happen & I like to be able to swap a new one in right away if someone damages one.